# Cordova Plugin Camera - Why my save image appear at the bottom of my gallery?

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I got this weird thing on my cordova project. After I click capture, the captured image save into my phone but it appear at the bottom of my picture gallery. Then my saved date on 01/01/1970 07:30 .

[image]

My question is how to change date into date that I capture the image? And why it happened?

This is my source code

```
function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        correctOrientation: true
    });
}
```

Cordova Plugin Camera: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

P.S: Currently I'm using Samsung S4.

Comment: Check your device date.

Comment: Is it related? because currently it shows current date and time. Impossible my device shows obsolete date.

Comment: I just needed a confirmation because if you capture a image then it saves according to current date and time of device.

Comment: I've the same problem (with s3 mini and galaxy nexus), but if I restart  the device (only galaxy nexus) the date of the photo is right.